# Как узнать размер программы? Python

Tags: python

Как можно узнать размер программы? Например есть в егэ задачи, где написано: при увеличении числа в K раз, она должна увеличиваться в N раз. Как узнать размер программы именно по мере поступления в неё данных? С помощью os можно узнать просто размер файла, но как узнать размер во время выполнения программы? **Если сравнивать программы по их размеру при выполнении программы, какой для этого есть способ?**

Os не подходит:

```
import os
folder_size = os.path.getsize('main.py')
print(folder_size)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего имеется ввиду использование оперативной памяти:

```
import os
import psutil
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print(process.memory_info().rss) # bytes
```

Comment: Скажите, результат вывел 12767232. В чём это из еряется?

Comment: @Евгений исправил ответ

Comment: спасибо, понял, 12767232 байта примерно получается полтора мегабайта

Comment: @ Вадим Александру скажите, почему при запуске кода сразу выводит огромное количество байт, если программа сама пуста?

Answer (score 0):

Для расчета время выполнения кода, вы можете пользоваться магическими функциями (iPython)

```
%%timeit
import os
folder_size = os.path.getsize('main.py')
print(folder_size)
```